# Wired connection disconnects

Tags: networking, wired

At work, when I plug in my wired connection it tries to connect for a few minutes, and then disconnects and I have to use the wireless connection.

How can I diagnose what is stopping the wired connection from working?

Edit:
This is from a Dell docking station. I found out this morning that it works when I use my USB to ethernet dongle, so it's something about the dock.

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 29
       serial: d0:ab:d5:40:22:48
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-73-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 ip=10.184.115.122 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:dc200000-dc203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@6:2.4
       logical name: enx98e743ba4432
       serial: 98:e7:43:ba:44:32
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.10.11 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

And the output of `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`

```
May 28 09:45:11 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <info>  [1622209511.8701] device (enx98e743ba4432): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (7abf30e2-7bae-30cf-b668-03e67eef548e)
May 28 09:45:11 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <info>  [1622209511.8703] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="7abf30e2-7bae-30cf-b668-03e67eef548e" name="Wired connection 1" pid=1948 uid=1000 result="success"
May 28 09:45:11 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <info>  [1622209511.8705] device (enx98e743ba4432): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 28 09:45:11 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <info>  [1622209511.8716] device (enx98e743ba4432): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 28 09:45:11 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <info>  [1622209511.8727] device (enx98e743ba4432): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 28 09:45:11 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <info>  [1622209511.8733] dhcp4 (enx98e743ba4432): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 28 09:45:56 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <warn>  [1622209556.7311] dhcp4 (enx98e743ba4432): request timed out
May 28 09:45:56 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <info>  [1622209556.7311] dhcp4 (enx98e743ba4432): state changed unknown -> timeout
May 28 09:45:56 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <info>  [1622209556.7313] device (enx98e743ba4432): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 28 09:45:56 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <warn>  [1622209556.7344] device (enx98e743ba4432): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
May 28 09:45:56 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <info>  [1622209556.7351] device (enx98e743ba4432): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 28 09:45:56 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <info>  [1622209556.7619] dhcp4 (enx98e743ba4432): canceled DHCP transaction
May 28 09:45:56 jeremy-XPS-13 NetworkManager[888]: <info>  [1622209556.7620] dhcp4 (enx98e743ba4432): state changed timeout -> done
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`..

Comment: You forgot to notify me that you updated your question with the lshw output, and I almost missed it. Anyway, you need to update the firmware on your Dell dock. Is it a D3000? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, thanks for the help. The dock is a WD19TB. I think that you might be right about the firmware and I'm working on updating that now.